# How to have react route path one/two/three?

Tags: react-router, react-router-v4

I would like to have something like this

```
        <Route
          path="/one/two/three"
          render={() => (
            <Component/>
          )}
          exact
        />
```

But it does not seem to work locally when I wrap it all into a `Router`. I only see the contents of the `Component` when it is just `/one`, but I would like to have `/one/two/three` as the path (being my root - user lands on that path).

Answer (score 1):

In `react-router-v4` you can have below routes only,

```
<Route path="/one" render={() => (<Component/>)} exact /> //Direct route without any params
```

or

```
<Route path="/one/:two" render={() => (<Component/>)} exact /> //Route with params, here `:two` is the parameter to route
```

If you want to use routes like in your example, then this can be achieve using [`BrowseRouter` `basename` attribute](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api),

```
<BrowserRouter basename="/one/two">
   <Route path="/three" render={() => (<Component/>)} exact />
</BrowserRouter>
```

And you `Link` should be like,

```
<Link to="/three"/> // renders <a href="/one/two/three">
```

Comment: Thanks for all the information!
Will have to look into that ;)

Comment: Managed to get it to work properly with just having path="/one/two/three".
I will try to answer my own question as well if somebody else is struggling with something similar

Answer (score 0):

Few reasons why this did not work for me.
I was missing `output: { publicPath: '/' },` in my webpack config.

And weirder thing was that I was using `PureComponent` instead of `Component` which totally broke the rending when redirecting to the next step with similar path(x/y/z) or using `Link`.